# Powershell Regular Expression to extract string between rounded parentheses from line in a log file

Tags: c#, .net, regex, powershell

This is a line in a log file:

```
$line = 'to devices Headset Earphone (Some Device)'
```

I need the result done with an one liner regex only (if possible):

```
$result = 'Some Device'
```

---

I have it working in two lines:

```
$InsideLoopLine = [regex]::Matches($Line, '^.*to devices Headset.*$')
                  [regex]::Matches($InsideLoopLine,'(?<=\().*(?=\))')
```

---

**New info 1 : @WiktorStribiżew**

Code:

```
$Line = 'to devices Headset Earphone (Some Device)'
([regex]::Matches($Line,'\bto devices Headset.*?\(([^()]+)')).Value
```

Result:

```
to devices Headset Earphone (Some Device
```

**New info 2**

Code:

```
$Line = 'to devices Headset Earphone (Some Device)'
([regex]::Matches($Line,'\bto devices Headset.*?\(([^()]+)')).Groups[1].Value
```

Result:

```
Some Device
```

Comment: You may run `$s -match '\bto devices Headset.*?\(([^()]+)'` and then the result will be in `$matches[1]`

Comment: `$s` is `$line` in your code.

Comment: Could't make this work, please see **New info 1 : @WiktorStribiżew**

Comment: I added an answer and offset the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `-match` with a pattern containing a capturing group, then, once there is a match, you may access your expected value using `$matches[1]`:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> $line = 'to devices Headset Earphone (Some Device)'
PS C:\Users\admin> $s -match '\bto devices Headset.*?\(([^()]+)' | Out-Null
PS C:\Users\admin> $matches[1]
Some Device
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cbto%20devices%20Headset.*%3F%5C%28%28%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%29&i=to%20devices%20Headset%20Earphone%20%28Some%20Device%29) at a .NET regex compatible testing site.

**Details**

- `\bto devices Headset` - whole word `to`, then space and `devices Headset` text
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars other than a newline, as few as possible
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than `(` and `)`.

You may check if there was a match before:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> $matched = $s -match '\bto devices Headset.*?\(([^()]+)'
PS C:\Users\admin> if ($matched) { Write-Host $matches[1] }
```

Alternative with `[regex]::Match`:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> $result = [regex]::Match($line, '(?<=\bto devices Headset.*?\()[^()]+').value
PS C:\Users\admin> $result
Some Device
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
$Query = [regex]::Matches($Line, "to devices Headset Earphone \((.*)\)")
$Query.Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: Just used your way and Wiktor's way combined, please see **New info 2**